# Can I use Visual Studio Plugins in Ranorex Studio?

Tags: visualstudio, ranorex

It seems that Ranorex does not support Visual Studio very well. E.g. the  `.rxrep` file is only compiled to code in Ranorex Studio but it won't be compiled to code in Visual Studio.

We have a very valuable tool chain in Visual Studio already (consisting of [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/), [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/), [Visual SVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/), [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/)) which I would not like to miss.

Is there a chance of making those plugins work in Ranorex Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranorex Studio is actually a customized version of [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx). 
There is a [list of 3rd party SharpDevelop Plugins](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Third-Party-AddIns).

Since not even a single of our plugins is listed (and ReSharper is very popular, so someone must have noticed), it seems that the plugin API between SharpDevelop and Visual Studio is **not compatible**.