# Alternative to Ranorex that integrates in Visual Studio

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, uiautomation, ranorex

Ranorex has its own IDE, Ranorex Studio. It seems that Ranorex does not integrate into Visual Studio very well. The only available [Ranorex blog entry](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/visual-studio-integration.html) describes the bare minimum of compiling a Ranorex script in Visual Studio. It does not offer the full functionality such as recording new objects into the repository, recording tests etc. Also, perhaps I can't [reuse my VS Plugins in Ranorex Studio (related question)](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22551/can-i-use-visual-studio-plugins-in-ranorex-studio).

For the following 2 reasons I don't want to miss Visual Studio:

- we have developers that are familiar and productive with it.
- our VS tool chain (consisting of [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/), [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/), [Visual SVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/), [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/)) works very well.

Therefore I'm looking for an alternative to Ranorex that integrates into Visual Studio. Unfortunately we have the full technology mix, so it must

- support SAP
- support Java applications
- support Browsers (Firefox and IE at least)
- support C# Winforms and WPF
- support Win32 applications

at the same time. This e.g. rules out [Silk Test](http://www.borland.com/en-GB/Products/Software-Testing/Automated-Testing/Silk-Test) which cannot identify SAP controls and Win32 controls in one session (we have a license and that's actually the reason why I'm looking for something else).

It must work on Windows and needn't support mobile applications. At the moment I don't care about the price. Commercial support must be available.

Comment: You can open Ranorex project using Visual Studio.

Comment: I know. And I said: "It does not offer the full functionality such as recording new objects into the repository, recording tests etc." That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

CodedUI seems to be the only solution.
Because Coded UI is the new testing framework from Microsoft so,it will 100% support the visual studio too.
And;

- support SAP-No idea
- support Java applications-Yes
- support Browsers (Firefox and IE at least)-Yes
- support C# Winforms and WPF-Yes
- support Win32 applications-Yes

So because of above explanations i think CodedUI will be the best solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14805)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake,But he is asking for a tool.And Coded UI is a tool where he can record and play back with fully supported by Visual Studio,

Comment: Then you might want to describe why you think it is the only option?

Comment: ooh..sure i Will And thank you very much for pointing out this to me.

Comment: Coded UI seems only available in VS 2015 Enterprise Edition ([comparison](https://www.visualstudio.com/de-de/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx))

Comment: SAP and Java are [not supported (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx)